# Android: Create different web from passing parameters in 1st activity using fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am a beginner in writing Android app.
I am confused when passing parameters from 1st activity to 2nd activity when 2nd activity is using fragment.

Here is what i would like to do. I would like to switch to webview activity that show corresponding webpage from the 1st activity parameter: routeName.

e.g. if routeName = A, display A.html. otherwise display default.html

Here are my coding:

In 1st activity:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), RouteInfoWebActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("routeName", routeName);
  startActivity(intent);
```

WebView Activity and Fragment class

```
    public class RouteInfoWebActivity extends FragmentHolder {
      private RouteInfoWebFragment routeInfoWebFragment;
      public RouteInfoWebActivity() {
        routeInfoWebFragment = new RouteInfoWebFragment(getIntent().getExtras().getString("routeName","defaultKey"));
      }
      protected Fragment fragment() { return routeInfoWebFragment; }

      @Override
      public void onBackPressed() {
        RouteInfoWebFragment routeWeb = (RouteInfoWebFragment) routeInfoWebFragment;
        WebView htmlView = routeWeb.getWebView();

        if (htmlView.canGoBack()) {
          htmlView.goBack();
        } else {
          super.onBackPressed();
        }
      }
    }


public class RouteInfoWebFragment extends LocalWebFragment {
    String url = "";
    public RouteInfoWebFragment(String routeName) {
    If (routename == 'A') {
        url == 'A.html';
        } else {
                url = 'default.html';
        }

        super("file:///android_asset/"+url, R.layout.route_web);
    } 


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater,
                             final ViewGroup container,
                             final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View routeWebView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        return routeWebView;
    } // onCreateView
```

However, I saw the warning in Fragment class when doing so:
Avoid non-default constructor in Fragment.

As I have set all corresponding properties in "LocalWebFragment" which I do not want to change it.

I know in Fragment I can use new instance to pass parameters before linking it to activity. However, wondering how can it be done on my case please? Is there any easy way to do so apart from creating a new Fragment parent?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the arguments in the form of a bundle and call **setArguments(Bundle bundle)** on your fragment object. In your fragment you can get the values by calling **getArguments()** and extracting what you want from that bundle.

**EDIT**

First of all, you need to get a object of your fragment and set the arguments.

```
Fragment fragment = new RouteInfoWebFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("routeName", routeName);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Then in your fragment class you can simply get the value of routeName

```
Bundle arguments = getArguments();
String routeName = arguments.getString("routeName");
```

Comment: Thanks Bilal for your help. Wondering if you would specify what should be done please? As in constructor we cannot define variable.....i am not quite sure how to do these steps. Thanks for your help again